# How to have password echoed as asterisks using getch()

Tags: c

I was trying to make a program that inputs a password from a user and stores the password as the string entered by the user but the display should contain asterisks, using getch() function. i am bamboozled by this. If anyone could help?

Comment: What have you done till now, to solve the problem? Show your efforts.

Comment: Your question is operating system specific. On Linux, you could try using `ncurses`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running on windows and your encoding is ASCII 
Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[256] = {0};
    char password[] = "password";
    char c;
    int pos = 0;

    printf("%s", "Enter password: ");
    do {
        c = getch();

        if( isprint(c) ) 
        {
            buffer[ pos++ ] = c;
            printf("%c", '*');
        }
        else if( c == 8 && pos )
        {
            buffer[ pos-- ] = '\0';
            printf("%s", "\b \b");
        }
    } while( c != 13 );

    if( !strcmp(buffer, password) )
        printf("\n%s\n", "Logged on succesfully!");
    else
        printf("\n%s\n", "Incorrect login!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `8` and `13` seem magic constants. Not all systems are ASCII nor Windows. You should replace them with `'\b'` and `'\n'` (or `'\r'`).

Comment: And `<conio.h>` is Windows specific. Don't exist on Linux or Posix.

Comment: Both of you are totally right! I added the assumptions in my answer, until PO specifies which environment he is working with :)