# how to show enter password in the form of Asterisks(*) on terminal

Tags: c++, c, unix

I want to write a simple `C` program to verify the `password`, for example if **password** is equal to **1234** then i want to print **Welcome** else **try again**. But the problem is as follows:

**I want to display enter password in the form of** **`*`**(**star**).
**for example**..if user will enter 1234 it will appear as `****` to avoid other person to see the entered password.

Can anyone give me a idea how to achieve it using c or c++.
***Platform : UNIX***

Comment: can you post what you have written first?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130979/how-to-have-password-echoed-as-asterisks-using-getch

Comment: You need to specify your platform as the solution to this is platform-specific

Comment: I am using unix platform

Comment: @PaulR: The [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25991101/694576) is better then the one given in the answer you linked.

Comment: or you can use the NO_ECHO flag on the fd 0, which make your tipyng invisible

Comment: It is funny how SO works. The original question get one downvote and this question already got eight upvotes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution to this is platform-specific, unfortunately.

On Linux or BSD, you can use the [readpassphrase](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readpassphrase) function (there is also [getpass](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpass), though it suffers from not allowing the buffer and buffer size to be provided by the caller. The documentation for the [GNU Lib C](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html) (link broken? try [this alternative](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#getpass) instead) library also provides an excellent guide on how to implement this yourself in terms of the lower level termios primitives, which you can use on other UNIX implementations in lieue of getpass).

On Windows, you can use [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) to disable the default echoing behavior (and thus echo your own characters such as the asterisk). You could then use SetConsoleMode to restore the echoing.

I should add, however, that this is a very poor form of authentication as it involves yet more passwords which are the bane of every user's existence (and not particularly secure, either). A better approach is to start a webserver in your application and output the URL on which the user should authenticate. The advantage to this approach is that, when the user navigates to this URL, that URL can then support delegated login to third party identity providers such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc. Even if you don't support third party identity providers, this approach comes with other benefits; if you have other web-based tools, this approach reduces the number of times that the user must authenticate (since the commandline tool and web based tools will share the same browser session) and allows you to implement the login flow only once, this approach also mitigates phishing risks (users can plainly see the host in the browser when they enter their credentials compared to entering credentials on the commandline where it is much easier to spoof a prompt, and if you only redirect to localhost at the last step but do the majority of the logic on a  remote host this approach also allows updates to the authorization flow to be deployed independently of the client commandline application which has important security benefits. That being said, a web based login such as this is not always the right approach. It is also worth looking into  alternative authentication mechanisms such as libpam (under libpam, you would use the function [pam_authenticate](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_authenticate) to authenticate the user rather than taking the password as input directly). It's worth investing some research to determine the best mechanism for your particular use case.

Comment: I'm sorry but did you just recommend that the OP output a URL to an authentication page from his console application???

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes I did. Yep, I know it's unusual and weird, but it's 2014... even if you are typing on the terminal, you still probably have access to a browser, and this is the only way to correctly and securely implement delegated login where you can be assured that your password (and, in some cases, second factor token) go only to the identity provider and not the console application.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Security or UX considerations are well beyond the scope of this question, and you cannot address them in a sensible manner without more context. I suggest you remove the last paragraph of your answer, it is pointless in this context.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald are they really? Engineering is all about understanding tradeoffs and understanding the larger context and considerations related to the topic at hand. Any idiot can regurgitate information memorized wholesale or look up the information of how to do the specific technical solution in the UNIX man pages. Knowing if it's a good idea or the available alternatives is, I believe, also extremely important. And, while you are correct that this suggestion may not always apply, I believe that this recommendation provides additional value to the answer.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Hinting at alternatives solution is a valid point, this is however not what you are doing. Instead, you present Browser-based third party authentication as *universally* superior to classical password authentication, which it is not. It is just a distinct paradigm, with distinct advantages, drawbacks, and applicability realms. Without more context stating “X is a very form of authentication” and “A better approach is Y” only spoils your credit, IMHO. Alternatives approaches are countless and we may quote `pam`, `ssh-keygen`, `kerberos`, … to help the OP getting started.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald fair enough. There are enough other benefits that I would argue it really is superior in most use cases; however, it's not always the right approach. I've updated the answer to also mention libpam as an alternative to directly taking the password.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and some other Unix-like platforms you can use `termios.h` for this. You need disable echo end canonical mode for output and print `*` after each got character.
There is C code example:

```
#include <termios.h>

struct termios term;

/* Disable echo input characters and buffered input by disabling ICANON*/
static void disable_echo() {
    struct termios new;
    if (tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &term) != 0) {
        perror("tcgetattr failed");
        exit(-1);
    }

    new = term;
    new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSAFLUSH, &new) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

/* Enable normal terminal state after getting password*/
static void enable_echo() {
    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSAFLUSH, &term) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

/* Read password which will be printed as `*` characters */
static void mask_getstr(char* buf, size_t size){
    char c = '\0';
    while (--size > 0 && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        *buf++ = c;
        putchar('*');
    }
    *buf = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include<iostream.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    void main()
    {
     char str[10];
     int i=0,x,y;
     cout<<"enter : ";
     while(1)
      { str[i]=getch();
        if(str[i]==13)
        break;
        if(str[0]==127||str[0]==8)
        continue;
        if(str[i]==127||str[i]==8)
        {
           i--;
           x=wherex();
           y=wherey();
           gotoxy(x-1,y);
           clreol();
         }
         else
         {
           cout<<"*";
           i++;
         }
       }
     if(strcmp(str,"1234")==0)
     cout<<"Welcome";
     else
     cout<<"Try again";
    }
```